# Is there major mode for editting CQL?

Tags: major-mode

I'm editting [CQL(Cassandra Query Language)](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html) on emacs and came to wonder if there's any dedicated major mode for editting CQLs.

Is there such one?

Comment: You can always use `list-packages` and then search among the packages using `C-s`/`C-r`. After some search though I can't seem to find anything related to `CQL` or even `cassandra`. It seems like you're out of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Xaldew mentioned, it seems there were no existing package.

So I started making one myself. -> [cql-mode](https://github.com/Yuki-Inoue/cql-mode)